# When I use RIGHT function in SSMS, it gives me blank result although there is no extra space

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to use RIGHT function in SQL Server Management Studio 17. But I continue getting a blank result. I used TRIM function to update my data, and then used LEN function to test the length, there is no extra space in this column.

[image]

[image]

But when I used TRIM function inside RIGHT, I can get the result I want.

[image]

So what is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Thank you!

```
SELECT RIGHT(FIRST_NAME,3) FROM Worker;
SELECT LEN(FIRST_NAME) FROM Worker;
SELECT RIGHT(TRIM(FIRST_NAME),3) FROM Worker;
```

Comment: You use trim() to get rid of spaces but how do you know they're spaces? Trim doesn't apply to other white space like CR, LF, tab, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you have use `char()` instead of `varchar()` for the `first_name`.  This automatically pads the name with spaces.

In general, you want to store strings as `varchar()`.  There are some circumstances where `char()` is useful -- such as for country codes which are uniformly 2- or 3- characters.  But in general, you want `varchar()`.

Comment: Right. That's the problem! Thank you very much, Gordon!

Comment: ...and if you can't change the type, convert to `varchar` first, e.g. `trim(convert(varchar(25), first_name))`..

Answer (score 0):

This is a known feature of using `LEN`.  Simply switch to `DATALENGTH` instead and you'll get the correct length for each column:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(FIRST_NAME) FROM Worker;
```

For `LEN`, taken here directly from the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
>   **excluding trailing blanks**.

And `DATALENGTH` in turn:

> Returns the number of bytes used to represent any expression.

If you would like to remove the trailing spaces from your existing rows, run a simple `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE Worker SET FIRST_NAME = TRIM(FIRST_NAME);
```

Comment: Wow. Right, the actual length is 25! Thank you! So how should I trim these spaces and update my table?

Comment: You can continue to use `RIGHT(TRIM(FIRST_NAME),3)` as you have been, or run an `UPDATE` statement to remove the extra spaces (something like: `UPDATE Worker SET FIRST_NAME = TRIM(FIRST_NAME);`)

Comment: I'd like to update it. I tried the UPDATE function but it doesn't work, I also tried RTRIM it doesn't work either.

Comment: I just realised (based off of Gordon's answer) that you are using `CHAR`s for your columns.  If you have `ANSI_PADDING ON` (which you probably do) then the columns will always be padded to the length of the `CHAR`.  Better to switch to a `VARCHAR` as Gordon has suggested.